# How to list my Walls [Screeps]

Tags: screeps

When I build a new wall using `Creep.build()`, it creates wall with 1 hit point. Now I am trying to create a creep which repairs these newly constructed walls. But I am not able to figure a good way to list and iterate on these wall objects.

`Game.structures` doesn't contain these since walls doesn't belong to a player. The only approach I could find was `Game.getObjectById(objectId)` where id is copy pasted from my game' ui
(right panel).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var repairit = creep.room.find(FIND_STRUCTURES, { 
   filter: (structure) => { 
       return ((structure.hits < 5000) && (structure.hits > 0))
   }
});
```

this repairs everything in a room, I'll give you a hint towards walls

```
structure.structureType == STRUCTURE_WALL
```

Comment: Walls are NOT your property, so they will not be found by `FIND_MY_STRUCTURES` I got trapped by this

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
    var walls = creep.room.find(FIND_STRUCTURES, {
  filter: (n) => n.structureType == STRUCTURE_WALL
  });
```